# Django dynamic ChoiceField and validation error

Tags: django, forms, validation, field

I have a field in my form

```
myFormList = [(u'Select',u'Select')]
myForm  = forms.ChoiceField(choices=myFormList)
```

and I am initializing it dynamically using

```
form.fields['myForm'].choices =  form.fields['myForm'].choices + anotherMyFormList
```

This is causing a validation error `Select a valid choice. ** is not one of the available 
 choices`

Usually I get rid of this error by

```
myForm  = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Select(choices=myFormList))
```

But since I have to use `form.fields['myForm'].choices`  while dynamically initializing I cannot use widgets.How do I do this `form.fields['myForm'].widgets.choices =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is superb.

`form.fields['myForm'].widgets.choices =` was actually my pseudo-code & that worked as such.